# CallKit UI to implemented UI

Tags: ios, objective-c, callkit

I used `CallKit`in my app and everything working fine. But what I want is when I received the first UI like the below image-

[image]

After sliding to answer I want to go to my implemented UI. How can I switch to my desired UI with the `slide to answer`?

Comment: Have you implemented delegates as well?

Comment: which one you are talking about?

Comment: Have a look :http://visieapp.blogspot.in/

https://www.raywenderlich.com/150015/callkit-tutorial-ios

Comment: If you are on the locked screen you can not go to your UI. You have to unlock the screen and go to your UI.